# Why have Postgres tables doubled in size after cancelling a DELETE?

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete, vacuum, autovacuum

I ran a simple delete query on a telemetries table to clear up some data but cancelled as it was taking really long. I noticed that after I cancelled the query some of the tables (all partitions of the telemetries table) are now taking up more than double the space they previously were. For example, a table that was previously 16GB is now 28GB (pg_size_pretty value).

I do not want to proceed with the delete because I want to keep the data but why have the tables swelled up so much? Would a `VACUUM FULL` help? If I run `VACUUM`, do I run the risk of actually deleting the data permanently?

I ran the following using psql;

```
delete from telemtries where timestamp < 1668987465000;
```

I cancelled with ctrl+c. I ran \s to check my query history aftwerwards and my delete query was not there. I'm using postgress 12.16

Comment: DELETE doesn't inflate the table, UPDATE could do this because of new versions. But that's not the case for a DELETE. Something else must have happend. VACUUM FULL can free space, but it does lock the table.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, read my comment to ErwinBrandstetter answer.

Comment: To your question add: 1) The DELETE query. 2) The method you used to cancel the query. 3) Postgres version. 4) Client you used.

Comment: In addition what tables increased in size and did that include `telemtries`?

Answer (score 3):

`DELETE` does not inflate tables. (`UPDATE` could, like [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens) commented.)

Aside from **triggers** that might do *anything* `ON DELETE`, the only remaining thing that comes to mind would be a [**`FOREIGN KEY` constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) with `ON DELETE SET NULL` or `... SET DEFAULT` referencing the target table of your `DELETE`. That would actually write new row versions for referencing rows, which linger as dead tuples in case of a `ROLLBACK`. Either way, it would bloat *those* tables, but not the target table of the `DELETE` (unless it's a self-referencing FK).

(Might also explain why the `DELETE` took so long. But there is a whole range of other possible reasons for that. You have not been overly specific.)

`VACUUM FULL` removes all bloat. See:

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37032/3684)

Comment: `DELETE does not inflate tables.` Huh? [VACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html): *25.1.1. Vacuuming Basics PostgreSQL's VACUUM command has to process each table on a regular basis for several reasons: To recover or reuse disk space occupied by updated or deleted rows.* I believe you are thinking about INSERT.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: No, I mean what I wrote. `DELETE` leaves dead tuples behind.  `VACUUM` can *shrink* the table as soon as dead tuples are dead for all. But `DELETE` does not inflate the table. It does not add tuples, unlike `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. You are tripping yourself here.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, canceling a long-running delete query might leave behind some dead (or obsolete) rows that were marked for deletion but were not yet physically removed from the table. These dead rows could contribute to the increase in table size.

**VACUUM FULL** requires an exclusive lock on the table, which means other transactions cannot access the table during the operation. This could lead to **downtime** for your application.

Instead of VACUUM FULL, you might want to try a **regular VACUUM** first. It's less aggressive and has fewer locking and performance implications.

```
VACUUM <your_table_name>;
```

After running vacuum, consider running **ANALYZE** to update statistics, which can help the query planner make better decisions about how to execute queries.

```
ANALYZE <your_table_name>;
```

If you're concerned about potential data loss, it's always a good idea to have a recent **backup** before performing maintenance operations on your database. This way, you can restore the data if anything unexpected happens.

Comment: A DELETE that is not committed but rolled back, doesn't result in dead tuples.